# How to obtain mdxAst from importing an mdx file in React/Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I am currently importing mdx files using the `gatsby-plugin-mdx` plugin and rendering them as pages using `createPage`. In the GraphQL query I have access to the ast tree:

```
const { mdx } = data
  const {
    frontmatter: { title, description, excerpt },
    body,
    mdxAST
  } = mdx
```

However I would like to import the mdx directly for use with `@reach/router` inclusion as a component instead of having it prewrapped as a page. So I do:

```
import FAQ, { _frontmatter } from 'components/mdx/faq.mdx'
```

This gives me the frontmatter and a component containing the transformed markdown. But the AST tree is not available in this export.

How can I either:

- get the ast tree
- make use of a plugin to transform the mdx files but not as a full page. Somehow make them available as components.